# Unable to automatically step into server. ASP.NET webforms application with ASMX service

Tags: asp.net, debugging, webforms, visual-studio-2019

I have a webforms application with ASP.NET and using ASMX web service. Its built on .NET 4 with Visual Studio.

I had it running fine when using previously with Windows 10.
Then I need to reinstall and format everything. So after the fresh installation of Windows 10, and Visual Studio 2019, when I opened this project and tried to debug it, it presented with the dialog with error in it which says "*Unable to automatically step into server. Debugging might be stopped on server.*". I have not changed anything in code. Just after fresh installation, this error comes. I have `"compilation debug=true"` set in web.config file. I did install ASP.NET versions before installing Visual Studio 2019. I repaired Visual Studio installation also. But error appears to be there.

Screenshot of error

[image: Error screenshot]

Need help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying so many unsuccessful things

1. Done *`"aspnet_regiis -i"`*
2. Tried reinstalling IIS and ASP.NET version from "Turn Windows Features On/Off"
3. Tried repairing Visual Studio installation
4. Tried reinstalling Visual Studio.

All were unsuccessful.
Then What I tried is, I removed ASMX web service reference from property pages of my project. Then again added the reference to web service via property pages. And then F5, and everything working fine again.

This might help others.